# Saving image from gallery to iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift and I am trying to save an image from the gallery of the phone (or the Internet) to my app. I found many tutorials showing how to view the image but not how to save it to my app (I guess to my assets folder) and use it later on. Can someone please pint me to the right direction?

Comment: I think 1stly you need to decide where you want to save it. There are a number of options. (1) Saving images to the PList is not advisable, however, (2) Core Data is an option. This all relates to saving data to the App, so after you switch it off and on again, the data is still there. i.e. it is called 'persistence'.

Comment: https://www.udemy.com with Rob Percival has some videos with a good background info on how to go about using Core Data. A good starting point. Although he also covers many other things there too. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

```
func saveImage (image: UIImage, path: String ) -> Bool{

    let pngImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    //let jpgImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)   // if you want to save as JPEG
    let result = pngImageData!.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)

    return result

}
```

Here is how to use the function later in your code:

```
saveImage(image, path: imagePath)
```

However before you can Save or Load anything you have to know the ‘path’ you are going to use.
We’ll need 3 things:

- a function to pinpoint the documents directory
- a file in the documents directory a function to pinpoint
- a variable to store the location ( path ) of the image we want to save

Here is how we are going to do that:

```
    func getDocumentsURL() -> NSURL {
    let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    return documentsURL
}

func fileInDocumentsDirectory(filename: String) -> String {

    let fileURL = getDocumentsURL().URLByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
    return fileURL.path!

}

// Define the specific path, image name
let imagePath = fileInDocumentsDirectory(myImageName)
```

Visit for more: http://helpmecodeswift.com/image-manipulation/saving-loading-images